# Is there a good skeleton for setting up an AWS SAM project the will consist of multiple lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-sam-cli

is there a source code for setting up a SAM project with the aim of adding multiple lambda functions (with shared code on some)?

It's also important that I could use the sam local feature for starting the api locally.

I checked the official AWS source code with

```
sam init
```

But it seems that the project is aimed for one function only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I made a cli to automate the process and ease the development of the microservice, [rocketsame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rocketsam)

I've went ahead and created a skeleton project that fits the needs described above, you can find it [here](https://github.com/nadav96/aws-lambda-microservice.git)

The project is mostly intended for python functions, but can support other types with some modifications.
It support rebuild for changed functions only, as well as running a local api, and building a big template for micro template (for each function).